# For some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ show that $\mathbb{N} \sim \mathbb{N} \setminus\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

My question is that:

Prove for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ show that $\mathbb{N}\sim\mathbb{N} \setminus\{ 1, 2, \ldots, m\}$

$\sim$ means they have same cardinality. It's an equivalence relation

What I know is that the set $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ is countable and finite.

Im not too sure of where to go from here...

Comment: What does $\sim$ mean here?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood ~ Means they have same caridnality. Its an equivalence relation

Comment: What does "$\mathbb{N}\{1, 2, . . . , m\}$" mean? Set subtraction (all naturals bigger than $m$)? Cartesian product? Something else?

Comment: @NoahSchweber darn it was supposed to have \ in there its set difference

Answer (score 1):

Two different hints for different methods of proving what you want:

1. You know that $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ is finite. If $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ is finite, what can you say about $\mathbb{N} = (\mathbb{N}\setminus \{1,2,\ldots,m\})\cup \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$?
2. The first few terms of $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ are $m+1,m+2,m+3,\ldots$.  Can you create a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\setminus \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$?

Comment: for part 1. would that be true because a countable union of countable stets is countable. However, Im supposed to show N=N\{1,2,...m} rather than assume it to be true

Comment: Well, a set is either finite or infinite.  If you can show it isn't finite (by way of a contradiction, as the first hint is trying to go), then it is infinite.  Infinite subsets of a countably-infinite set are countably-infinite.  And in your statement that a countable union of countable sets is countable, you're going too far.  What can you say about a finite union of finite sets?

Comment: I think id rather prove it the 2nd way where the bijection would be something like g: N->N\{1,2...} via g(a):= m+a where a=1,2...

Comment: @jimmbo Yep, that's the bijection (the other answers say as much as well).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1, 2, . . . , m\}$. This is much more concrete than I suspect you think; often, when thinking about bijections between infinite sets, it's easy to make things much more complicated than they actually are.

I find it helpful to think step by step:

- Where should $f$ map $1$ to? Well, the first element of $A$ is $m+1$, so let's send $1$ there (just to have somewhere to put it).
- What about $f(2)$? Well, $m+1$ is taken, so let's send $2$ to $m+2$.
- Do you see a pattern now? Can you show that the suggested $f$ is in fact a bijection?

---

See also [Hilbert's Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).

Comment: ok I definitely see this pattern. So all I am trying to prove is that f(x)=m+x is a bijection? Meaning I just show that f(x) is onto and one-to-one?

Comment: @jimmbo Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

The bijection you wish to define is just one that is shifted. Consider the map given by;

$$\alpha(i) = m+i$$

where $i = 1,2,3,..$ I am not sure how you define your natural numbers but if it includes zero just do $m+i+1$ and then you can have $i = 0,1,2,...$